# I couldnt bind Image source

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Here is binding:

```
<Image Width="16" Height="16"  Source="{Binding SwitchForImage, Converter={StaticResource stringToImage}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
</Image>
```

and here is the Convertor

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string type = (string)value;
        BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
        logo.BeginInit();
        logo.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/"+type+@"Icon.png");
        logo.EndInit();
        return logo;
    }
```

when i run ,gives this exception "Cannot locate resource 'resources/*icon.png' ".But i put png files into folder named Resources.I am creating library.These all in library.For test i used it,and then occured this problem.

I added png files as"include to project".Build action is "Content".But i tried others also(Resource,Embedded resource)

[Answer] 
I changed Build Action to Resource and changed Convert like that:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "/AutoComplete;component/Resources/" + (string)value + "Icon.png";
    }
```

And everything work normally.

Comment: Is the folder Resources in same assembly as xaml files or is it in some other assembly? Also, are your png files used as Embedded resource or loose files?

Comment: no all files in parent folder.I checked **bin** folder,and saw that there is a dll file and 1 folder named Resources which png files in it.

Comment: If you dont use your png files as embedded resource and use them as loose files, you would need to use siteOfOrigin:,,, instead of application:,,, try it and see if it works..!!.. Also i think Resources folder shouldnt be in bin folder, it should be in parent folder..!!

Comment: it is in parent folder.but it created automaticly when  i tested it(in one solution i have 2 projects,1st is library,2nd is tester.)

Comment: If BuildAction is Embedded Resource, then application:,,, syntax should work I suppose..!!

Comment: maybe i give wrong UriSource ?

Comment: Reading this link for Pack URI syntax and options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx will guide you to the solution I suppose..!!

Comment: i tried siteOfOrigin and see now that it goes to  **\WpfApplication1\bin\Release\Resources\namespaceIcon.png'.** which i said for testing i created other project.How to make that go to library directory not to testers bin directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Build Action to Resource and changed Convert method like that:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return "/AutoComplete;component/Resources/" + (string)value + "Icon.png";
}
```